# How to use pattern matching with function values in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, higher-order-functions

I have several functions with same input and output types initialized in an object

```
object Utils {
  def f1(value: Int): Double = ???
  def f2(value: Int): Double = ???
  def f3(value: Int): Double = ???
}
```

I have a list of higher order values for those functions:

```
val x = List(Utils.f1, Utils.f2)
```

How can I use pattern matching to check which functions of those declared in the object are contained in x? I would like to obtain something similar to the following code:

```
x(0) match {
  case Utils.f1 => ...
  case Utils.f2 => ...
}
```

Comment: This is not possible in the general sense, function equality is a NP-Hard problem, but they may be subtle workarounds. However, needing to know which function you have feels weird, this seems like an **XY-Problem**, care to explain why exactly do you want to do this, what is the meta-problem behind the question?

Comment: In my project I have a set of objects where one of their value is a higher order function, this value describes the behaviour of the object to some events happening.

Based on this value, I want to represent these objects differently in the GUI.

Comment: You can create your own **ADT** to encapsulate those functions, so you can pattern match against that to determine which function you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be possible if you make `f1`, `f2`, `f3` `val`s. Please notice that upon pattern matching the equality by reference will be used

```
object Utils {
  val f1: Int => Double = _ * 10.0
  val f2: Int => Double = _ * 20.0
  val f3: Int => Double = _ * 30.0
}

val x: Seq[Int => Double] = List(Utils.f1, Utils.f2)

import Utils._

x(0) match {
  case `f1` => println(1)
  case `f2` => println(2)
  case `f3` => println(3)
}
```

If you keep `f1`, `f2`, `f3` `def`s then

```
object Utils {
  def f1(value: Int): Double = value * 10.0
  def f2(value: Int): Double = value * 20.0
  def f3(value: Int): Double = value * 30.0
}

val x: Seq[Int => Double] = List(Utils.f1, Utils.f2)
  
val f1: Int => Double = Utils.f1
val f2: Int => Double = Utils.f2
val f3: Int => Double = Utils.f3

x(0) match {
  case `f1` => println(1)
  case `f2` => println(2)
  case `f3` => println(3)
}
```

produces `MatchError`.

Comment: What if the input type is generic?
def standardFoodEffect[A <: Int](value: A): Set[Double]

How can i convert this into val?

Comment: @Snorlite In Scala 2 there are no polymorphic functions as first-class citizens. You'll have to emulate them with wrappers `trait Poly { type B; def apply[A](a: A): B }` `val standardFoodEffect = new Poly { type B = Set[Double]; def apply[A <: Int](a: A) = ??? }` like `shapeless.Poly`.

Comment: Or `trait Poly[Upper] {type B; def apply[A <: Upper](a: A): B}`, `val standardFoodEffect = new Poly[Int]...`

Comment: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values

Answer (score 4):

You can't match against functions, it has no meaningfully defined equality.